# finding folder name recursively and assigning it to a variable

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, directory

I am in a folder path. There is a folder named `dir`. There is one more folder inside `dir` but I don't know the name. How to find it and assign it to a variable.

PS: I want to run this on multiple folders so need a script which works like above.

Comment: Please provide an example of the file structure, and show what you'd be trying to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set -- dir/*/
```

Doing the above would set the `$1` to the pathname of the first directory found in `dir`. `$2` would be the pathname of the second one, etc.  And `$@` would be the list of all directory pathnames in `dir`.

Note that the trailing `/` at the end of `dir/*/` is significant.  without it, you would possibly pick up names of regular files as well.

Example, given the following:

```
.
`-- dir
    |-- A
    |   `-- file2
    |-- B
    |   `-- file2
    |-- C
    |   `-- file2
    `-- file1
```

```
$ set -- dir/*/

$ echo "$1"
dir/A/

$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
dir/A/
dir/B/
dir/C/

$ myfolder="$1"
$ printf 'My folder is "%s"\n' "$myfolder"
My folder is "dir/A/"
```